# swift parsing CSV file from API does not separate with the delimiter

Tags: ios, swift, csv

I'm trying to pass the data into the cells of a tableView. The networking communication works because The list of items appear in the first cell.

For example the list come like: sensor1, sensor2, sensor3,....
but it should be like :

sensor1

sensor2

...

this is how I'm **parsing the CSV file**

```
struct ParseCVS {

func parseURL (contentsOfURL: NSURL, encoding: NSStringEncoding) -> ([String])?{
    let rowDelimiter = ","
    var nameOfSensors:[String]?

    do {
        let content = try String(contentsOfURL: contentsOfURL, encoding: encoding)
        print(content)

        nameOfSensors = []

        let columns:[String] = content.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.newlineCharacterSet()) as [String]


        for column in columns {
            let values = column.componentsSeparatedByString(rowDelimiter)
            if let nameOfSensor = values.first {
                nameOfSensors?.append(nameOfSensor)
            }    
        }

    }
    catch {
        print(error)
    }

    return nameOfSensors

  }

}
```

and this is my **TableViewController**

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

// Array which will store my Data
var nameOfSensorsList = [String]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    guard let wetterURL = NSURL(string: "http://wetter.htw-berlin.de/phpFunctions/holeAktuelleMesswerte.php?mode=csv&data=1")
            else {
                return
              }

    let parseCSV = ParseCVS()
    nameOfSensorsList = parseCSV.parseURL(wetterURL, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!

    tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100.0

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

}

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return nameOfSensorsList.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MenuTableViewCell

    cell.nameLabel?.text = nameOfSensorsList[indexPath.row] 

    return cell
  }


}
```

if someone have any ideas I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Sorry, could you elaborate a bit more on what the issue is? im confused on what you're getting from the network call, what you get when you parse your data, and what you're expecting on possibly both cases.

Comment: hi! what i'm getting is a list of items, all of the in a row. What I want is to get one item per row. Some how my App cannot recognize the comma and therefore it cannot separate the items properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've forgotten to iterate through an array of "values".
Try something like this:

```
for column in columns {
    let values = column.componentsSeparatedByString(rowDelimiter)

    print(values.count)
    for value in values {
        nameOfSensors?.append(value)
    }
}
```