# swift 3.1 how to get array or dictionary from CSV

Tags: csv, parsing, swift3

How could I use data in this kind of CSV file? Or how could I print for example row 2 value for "inside" column and assign it to a property / entity?

I have this kind of file I got from excel file converted to Numbers, I'd like to grab data for each column and use them.

The original CSV file opened in numbers:

[image]

The console output I got:

[image]

Using this methods:

```
func readDataFromCSV(fileName:String, fileType: String)-> String!{
        guard let filepath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: fileName, ofType: fileType)
            else {
                return nil
        }
        do {
            var contents = try String(contentsOfFile: filepath, encoding: .utf8)
            contents = cleanRows(file: contents)
            return contents
        } catch {
            print("File Read Error for file \(filepath)")
            return nil
        }
    }


func cleanRows(file:String)->String{
    var cleanFile = file
    cleanFile = cleanFile.replacingOccurrences(of: "\r", with: "\n")
    cleanFile = cleanFile.replacingOccurrences(of: "\n\n", with: "\n")
    //        cleanFile = cleanFile.replacingOccurrences(of: ";;", with: "")
    //        cleanFile = cleanFile.replacingOccurrences(of: ";\n", with: "")
    return cleanFile
}
```

SOLUTION thanks to Jens Meder

using

```
 func csv(data: String) -> [[String]] {
        var result: [[String]] = []
        let rows = data.components(separatedBy: "\n")
        for row in rows {
            let columns = row.components(separatedBy: ";")
            result.append(columns)
        }
        return result
    }
```

in viewDidLoad

```
var data = readDataFromCSV(fileName: kCSVFileName, fileType: kCSVFileExtension)
    data = cleanRows(file: data!)
    let csvRows = csv(data: data!)
    print(csvRows[1][1]) // UXM n. 166/167
```

Comment: What's the problem? It seems you've already read the data.

Comment: yes I read it , but I only got a long string, How could I print for example row 2 value for "inside" column and assign it to a property / entity?

Comment: Did you try searching Stack Overflow? Do you really imagine you are the first person ever to want to split a CSV file into components?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [swift parsing CSV file from API does not separate with the delimiter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35857330/swift-parsing-csv-file-from-api-does-not-separate-with-the-delimiter)

Comment: obviously!, infact this code is the result of my searching and another question of mine, but many explained to me that CSV is very hard to manipulate, and I'd better change the file extension, the matter is that it's not possible. More, all solutions are tailored to different CSV files and I don't know how to solve this kind of problem. Finally design patterns change a lot between swift versions and answers, so I find very hard even to understand the staples of converting CSV to a dictionary or array

Answer (score 35, accepted):

What you want to do is splitting up the string in rows and then into columns (basically a two dimensional array of Strings). Swift already provides the [`components`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/string/1690777-components) method for that on `String` structs.

```
func csv(data: String) -> [[String]] {
    var result: [[String]] = []
    let rows = data.components(separatedBy: "\n")
    for row in rows {
        let columns = row.components(separatedBy: ";")
        result.append(columns)
    }
    return result
}
```

Then you can access any value via:

```
var data = readDataFromCSV(fileName: kCSVFileName, fileType: kCSVFileExtension)
data = cleanRows(file: data)
let csvRows = csv(data: data)
print(csvRows[1][1]) //UXM n. 166/167.
```

Comment: thanks for your help, I added a test to my question with your code, but I think I did not understand what to put in data: <your file string> could you check if I misunderstood something?

Comment: with `<your file string>` I was referring to the result of your `readDataFromCSV` method. It is basically the content of the csv file that you read into a String.

Comment: done! I should use cswRows, updated the entire answer with your solution, thanks for your help!

Comment: This isn't going to work if you have special characters in the values, like a `;` in one of the strings. And there are more escaping rules. It would be better to find a mature library to parse this for you.

Answer (score 19):

**Swift 4**

Sometime CSV file is more complicated such as special characters (e.g. comma), the values are surrounded by double quotes as examples below:

```
Hello, "Complicated String, with a comma inside", 123
```

In this case, I use:

```
let dataString: String! = String.init(data: data!, encoding: .utf8)
var items: [(String, String, String)] = []
let lines: [String] = dataString.components(separatedBy: NSCharacterSet.newlines) as [String]

for line in lines {
    var values: [String] = []
    if line != "" {
        if line.range(of: "\"") != nil {
            var textToScan:String = line
            var value:NSString?
            var textScanner:Scanner = Scanner(string: textToScan)
            while textScanner.string != "" {
                if (textScanner.string as NSString).substring(to: 1) == "\"" {
                    textScanner.scanLocation += 1
                    textScanner.scanUpTo("\"", into: &value)
                    textScanner.scanLocation += 1
                } else {
                    textScanner.scanUpTo(",", into: &value)
                }

                 values.append(value! as String)

                 if textScanner.scanLocation < textScanner.string.count {
                     textToScan = (textScanner.string as NSString).substring(from: textScanner.scanLocation + 1)
                 } else {
                     textToScan = ""
                 }
                 textScanner = Scanner(string: textToScan)
            }

            // For a line without double quotes, we can simply separate the string
            // by using the delimiter (e.g. comma)
        } else  {
            values = line.components(separatedBy: ",")
        }

        // Put the values into the tuple and add it to the items array
        let item = (values[0], values[1], values[2])
        items.append(item)
        print(item.1)
        print(item.2)
        print(item.3)
     }
 }
```

It is just written in Swift 4, the original is from https://www.appcoda.com/core-data-preload-sqlite-database/

Comment: This solution doesn't work either. If a value has a newline inside (which is possible if the value has double quotes surrounding it), then this will also not parse correctly.

Comment: It's also not scalable. This solution makes the assumption that we'll only have 3 columns, but if you're working with a dataset of say 30 columns, you shouldn't be defining 30-element tuples

Answer (score 19):

Starting from iOS15 there is a new Official framework called `TabularData`, try to use it.

```
import TabularData

let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "csvFileName", withExtension: "csv")!
let result = try? DataFrame(contentsOfCSVFile: url)
print(result)
```

[image]

Then you can convert them into the data model you need

[More Detail About TabularData(WWDC)](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/tech-talks/10100)

Comment: I think you're on to something here

Comment: This should be the accepted answer in 2022

Answer (score 13):

This is for CSV file for swift 4.2

```
var dataArray = [[String]]()
if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "file", ofType: "csv") {
    dataArray = []
    let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)
    do {
        let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
        let dataEncoded = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
        if  let dataArr = dataEncoded?.components(separatedBy: "\r\n").map({ $0.components(separatedBy: ";") }) {
            for line in dataArr {
                dataArray.append(line)
            }
        }
    } catch let jsonErr {
        print("\n Error reading CSV file: \n ", jsonErr)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 13):

**Swift 5.0**
.scanLocaion and .scanUpTo() were deprecated in iOS13.  Here's a working version of Chhaileng's answer.

```
 func openCSV(fileName:String, fileType: String)-> String!{
    guard let filepath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: fileName, ofType: fileType)
        else {
            return nil
    }
    do {
        let contents = try String(contentsOfFile: filepath, encoding: .utf8)

        return contents
    } catch {
        print("File Read Error for file \(filepath)")
        return nil
    }
}

 func parseCSV(){

    let dataString: String! = openCSV(fileName: "MeislinDemo", fileType: "csv")
    var items: [(String, String, String)] = []
    let lines: [String] = dataString.components(separatedBy: NSCharacterSet.newlines) as [String]

    for line in lines {
       var values: [String] = []
       if line != "" {
           if line.range(of: "\"") != nil {
               var textToScan:String = line
               var value:String?
               var textScanner:Scanner = Scanner(string: textToScan)
            while !textScanner.isAtEnd {
                   if (textScanner.string as NSString).substring(to: 1) == "\"" {


                       textScanner.currentIndex = textScanner.string.index(after: textScanner.currentIndex)

                       value = textScanner.scanUpToString("\"")
                       textScanner.currentIndex = textScanner.string.index(after: textScanner.currentIndex)
                   } else {
                       value = textScanner.scanUpToString(",")
                   }

                    values.append(value! as String)

                if !textScanner.isAtEnd{
                        let indexPlusOne = textScanner.string.index(after: textScanner.currentIndex)

                    textToScan = String(textScanner.string[indexPlusOne...])
                    } else {
                        textToScan = ""
                    }
                    textScanner = Scanner(string: textToScan)
               }

               // For a line without double quotes, we can simply separate the string
               // by using the delimiter (e.g. comma)
           } else  {
               values = line.components(separatedBy: ",")
           }

           // Put the values into the tuple and add it to the items array
           let item = (values[0], values[1], values[2])
           items.append(item)
           print(item.0)
           print(item.1)
           print(item.2)
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: This parser (like any of the parsers on this page) is flawed. It starts off splitting lines by newline, which is an incorrect assumption.
A csv file might contain a newline as it's value when it is in double quotes. So the only way to go is properly parse from the beginning, use a mini-state machine, and don't assume anything