# Reading data from Excel document in a Swift app

Tags: swift, excel, firebase

I have an Excel document with some tables and a lot of data points. I'd like to read from it to populate some UICollectionView cells and other parts of my app.

Something like:

```
Country | Temperature | Cost
-----------------------------
Spain   | 23          | 80
France  | 26          | 60
Italy   | 31          | 120
```

I'd like an external database so I can change the info without having to update the app. I use Firebase in my other apps but I don't want to rely on something I might have to pay for in the future.

So I was thinking of turning the Excel doc into a Google Sheet and reading from that using the API. But am I just making my life more difficult? It seems like a clunky solution.

Answer (score 6):

1- Open **Excel** and export the file as `CSV`

2- Use this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43295163/swift-3-1-how-to-get-array-or-dictionary-from-csv) to read it as array

Comment: But this would be importing it to the Swift app, and accessing it that way. I wouldn't be able to edit the information without updating the app.

Comment: upload it to server

Comment: Can i insert data in excel file using ios swift ?

Answer (score 3):

If you don't need to edit the Excel document and it's stored in the new XLSX format, there's an open-source library written in Swift that allows you to parse this file and read the cell data from it: [CoreXLSX](https://github.com/CoreOffice/CoreXLSX).

Answer (score -4):

Excel is not precisely a database or a datastore. If you want an app then build an app - that means having a datastore/database and a User Interface, UI. As for updating data points you can automate that (preferable) or you can use your UI to manually update.

Comment: What would be a way of automating it?
The data wouldn't be user data, but more like extra content.

Comment: If the data source does not have a means to push on update, you'll have to stand up a server, maybe a node.js server, to periodically ask the endpoint what it's got.