# Swift Convert a .numbers file or a xlsx to a csv file programmatically

Tags: swift, csv

For a project I'm working on I have a CSV reader to read user input. But that's quite an annoying UX, cause the user has the data in a google sheet/ execl (xlsx) format or numbers format. So if the user did not convert the file to CSV before uploading, they need to navigate to the Numbers app and export the file to file to CSV there.

So I was thinking how can I make this better, first thought, yeah just read the xlsx or numbers file ..... One day googling and trying some stuff, I still didn't find a good approach.

I would love to hear your input, I'm sure somebody out there has experience with this.

I'm thinking about creating an API for it. But I prefer to handle it natively in swift.

Thanks!

Comment: It’s a noble goal, but likely impractical given the lack of documentation on the `.numbers` file format, AFAIK. For xlsx, perhaps https://stackoverflow.com/a/53263886/1271826. I don’t know of anything equivalent for Numbers.

Comment: Looking at the numbers file, it appears to be a fairly hairy, binary file format…

Comment: These formats use private/proprietary file encoding. Some external lib can read/write them, usually you'll need to pay for them (since it's "hard", it's their business).